# have the ( ) in the string how to re.sub to \( \)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, escaping

i want to re.sub the string which have the  `'abc(abc)abc'`  to the `'abc\(abc\)abc'`

```
string = 'abc(abc)abc 
sub_l_string = re.sub(r'\(','\(',string) 
sub_r_string = re.sub(r'\)','\)',sub_l_string) 
pp(sub_r_string)
```

it suppose to print `'abc\(abc\)abc'`,however it print
`'abc\\(abc\\)abc'`

can anyone help? thanks!

Comment: Your code [works well](https://ideone.com/v6765T).

Answer (score 1):

One option could be a single replacement with a pattern,  matching from an opening parenthesis and asserting a closing one, and add a backslash in the replacement before and after the full match `\g<0>`

```
import re

regex = r"\([^()]*(?=\))"
s = "abc(abc)abc"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\\\g<0>\\", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/U6kykC)

---

Or with a capture group `g<1>`

```
import re

regex = r"(\([^()]*)\)"
s = "abc(abc)abc"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\\\g<1>\\)", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TyOVbG)

**Output**

```
abc\(abc\)abc
```

Comment: i try the code it shows `'abc\\(abc\\)abc'`